# Count and insert comments from Xoops database

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am trying to convert Xoops posts to Wordpress. As part of that, I want to get comment count for a topic. Post and replies are on same "topic_id". How to count them and post it in to new column?

**DB current status**

```
topic_id | subject             |comment_count|
+________+_____________________+_____________+
1    | welcome             | 
1    | Re: welcome         |
2    | hello world         |
2    | Re: hello world     |
2    | Re: hello world     |
3    | hello friends       |
```

from here I want to take the (count of topic_id - 1) as the number of replays (comment count). Guide me to query in MYSQL

I want to place the output in the same table. (comment_count)

**DB expected output**

```
   | topic_id | subject             |comment_count|
   +________+_____________________+_____________+
   | 1   | welcome             | 1 
   | 1   | Re: welcome         | 1
   | 2   | hello world         | 2
   | 2   | Re: hello world     | 2
   | 2   | Re: hello world     | 2
   | 3   | hello friends       | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select *,t2.comment_count  from table t1 
     join
     (
       select count(*),CONCAT('Re', ' ', subject) 
        as replay,topic_id as comment_count 
        from table 
        where suject=replay group by topic_id
     ) as t2 on t1.topic_id=t2.topic_id
```

Comment: This will give `comment_count` = 1 for the `3   | hello friends` it should be 0 since it had no comments replays.

Comment: how can it be zero when there is one

Comment: It should be zero since there is no replay comments to this comment. Look at the OP sample data. The `1   | welcome` has `commnet_count` = 1 since it has 1 replay but the `3 | hello friends` doesn't has any replays.

Comment: instead of '0' null is ok.
and i want to update in the same table

Comment: @MahmoudGamal will this make any difference ..and 10x for pointing my fault .actull isn't it a bad db design practice ???

Comment: @ arun , finally this will data will be splited as wp_comments and wp_posts.

Comment: @arun will it update to the same table. i want like that. 

table name = wp_posts_temp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    xoops.topic_id, topic, xoops2.commentCount
FROM 
    xoops JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        xoops.topic_id,
        commentCount = COUNT(1) - 1
    FROM 
        xoops   
    GROUP BY 
        xoops.topic_id
        ) AS xoops2 ON xoops.topic_ID = xoops2.topic_ID
```

Comment: I changed with table names.

is it correct 

SELECT 
    sh_bb_posts.topic_id, topic, wp_posts_temp.comment_count
FROM 
    sh_bb_posts JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        sh_bb_posts.topic_id,
        comment_count = COUNT(1) - 1
    FROM 
        sh_bb_posts  
    GROUP BY 
        sh_bb_posts.topic_id
        ) AS wp_posts_temp ON sh_bb_posts.topic_ID = wp_posts_temp.topic_ID

Comment: Looks correct to me :) If you want it to be 100% unambiguous, use the below. I removed the table prefix from the sub query, and added the table name to the topic-part of the SELECT:

SELECT 
 sh_bb_posts.topic_id, 
 sh_bb_posts.topic, 
 wp_posts_temp.comment_count 
FROM 
 sh_bb_posts JOIN 
 ( 
  SELECT 
   topic_id, 
   comment_count = COUNT(1) - 1 
  FROM 
   sh_bb_posts 
  GROUP BY 
   sh_bb_posts.topic_id 
 ) AS wp_posts_temp ON sh_bb_posts.topic_ID = wp_posts_temp.topic_ID